# Button order in Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-alertdialog

I'm inflating an AlertDialog to let the user send comments. Fairly simple. But I'm getting this Lint warning:

> Layout uses the wrong button order for API >= 14: Create a layout-v14/chat_comment_dialog.xml file with 
>    opposite order: Cancel button should be on the left (was "@string/send | Cancel", should be "Cancel | @string/
>    send")

So, yeah, this is the solution, create a specific layout for API >= 14 and invert the order. But....REALLY? Is this REALLY the official suggestion? To set one order in some devices and a different one in others? As a user, I would feel very confused. Should I ignore this Lint advice, or otherwise, follow this new pattern for a set of devices (which I think is rather confusing)

Anyway, here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="@string/review" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

By the way, I have to inflate the Buttons in the XML and not in the AlertDialog.Builder (maybe this way the buttons will be automatically order themselves), because any onClickListener you set to the Builder's deafult button will dissmiss the dialog, and I have to avoid that behaviour to control the Dialog myself.

Comment: You should follow the advice, yes. You can follow reluctantly, though, but you have to follow. Surely you can have a separate ok/cancel layout (2 versions) and <include> it everywhere.

Comment: "But....REALLY? Is this REALLY the official suggestion?" Yup it sure is =/ They changed the default order of the buttons on Dialogs at that API level. If you create a dialog with the builder instead of via xml layout you'll see this change as well. Whether it was a good idea is certainly up for debate, but nonetheless they chose to run with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you plan on targeting API level >14 then you should **definitely** follow the design specification. Changes were made to the layout of dialogs to increase usability.

As a user you would not be confused because you are only using a single device at a single API level.  What **is** confusing is when a developer create non-standard UI's. Not following the standard will lead to frustration and confusion. For example if all the other apps on a user's phone (API level >14) create standard dialogs with the proper button order and your app has the button order wrong it lead to users hitting Cancel instead of Send and visa versa. Surely this will confuse and annoy the user.

It really isn't that much extra work to check the API level on the device and to provide the appropriate layout. If you design your app well it shouldn't require more than a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is not the extra work what annoys me. In fact, I have done this already, since you're right about the user confussion in one single device. But the confussion is still there if the user uses or has used other Android devices. Anyway, this is just another bit in Android fragmentation.

Comment: There is no way to know what devices a user could possibly have and each user that has multiple devices will surely not have the same set of devices. Instead of playing a guessing game its **always** better to implement the standards.  Its very easy for users to contextualize an UI to a specific device. Ie UI difference between my Mac and Linux comptuers don't make either one more difficult to use. Instead problems arrise when either a mac or linux application is designed like an application for another platform.

Comment: Sure, but we are talking about apps for the **same** platform. Not comparing two different ones' standards. I'm not trying to guess the user's devices, but the same way, we cannot assume that the user stack to a single one. As a developer, I always try to addapt myself to the new patterns as soon as they're "established", and implementing them backwards, but I see no point in this one. Maybe is just because my head is used to see the possitive button in the left, and the negative one in the right.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your last comment, you can still do all the AlertDialog stuff from code and be able to control things like when the dialog is dismissed, just use a `View.onClickListener` instead of `DialogInterface.onClickListener`:

```
AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_text, null).show();
```

and then add the listener afterwards:

```
d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        .setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {...});
```

Adding the alternative listener prevents the dialog from automatically being dismissed when the button is pressed.